# How to configure Spring-MVC to use Groovy Templates?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, groovy

So far I have configured

```
<beans>
    <bean id="groovyMarkupConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.groovy.GroovyMarkupConfigurer">
        <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="classpath:/WEB-INF/templates/" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

and

```
<bean id="groovyMarkupViewResolver"     
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.groovy.GroovyMarkupViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/templates/" p:suffix=".tpl"/>
```

and I have I file named test.tpl in /WEB-INF/templates/. Than I do the following in my controller:

return "test";

But I keep getting: Could not resolve view with name 'test' in servlet with name 'spring'

BTW: This is a plain Spring MVC project and not a spring boot project.

Comment: Your first will never work as `/WEB-INF/` isn't in the classpath. Make sure you don't have other view resolvers, if you do make sure that the ordering is correct.

Comment: Adding the stack trace / error from the console might help (as in the full stack trace / logging instead of a snippet).

Comment: Also your current config would lead to locate files in the classpath in `WEB-INF/templates/WEB-INF/templates`... Looks too me that isn't what you want...

Comment: Thanks I had to omit the prefix Setting in the  ViewResolver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong to start with.

1. `/WEB-INF/` isn't part of the classpath. So your current configuration of the `GroovyMarkupConfigurer` will locate the files in the wrong directory. Remove `classpath:` from the configuration.

   ```
   <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/templates/" />
   ```
2. Your current configuration will try to load the `classpath/WEB-INF/templates/WEB-INF/templates/test.tpl` due to 1 and due to the fact you provided a prefix. Remove the prefix.

   ```
   <bean id="groovyMarkupViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.groovy.GroovyMarkupViewResolver" p:suffix=".tpl"/>
   ```

If you have more `UrlBasedViewResolver`s then you are in a bit of a pickle as that won't work, they will always return a URL to redirect/forward to for rendering a view.